# Apollo client query does not recognize than my variable type is correct

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

NUmber 1500 goes through well, if I send any random name of variable no error, but if I send
parseInt(born) as setBornTo: then I have error bad request 400

```
export const EDIT_AUTHOR = gql`
  mutation editAuthor($name: String!,$setBornTo: Int
  ) {
    editAuthor(name: $name, setBornTo: 1500)  {
      name
      born
    }
  }
```

I send it so

```
console.log(typeof(parseInt(born)))
editAuthor({ variables: { 'name':name,'setBornTo':parseInt(born)
    }}, {    refetchQueries: [ { query: ALL_BOOKS } ,{ query: ALL_PERSONS}]  })
```

No error with name of even if I send any random named variable, too

Comment: what's the value of born before the parseInt?

Comment: also, you should always specify a radix when using parseInt `parseInt(born, 10)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description

Comment: any value. It can be "1" or "1991"

Answer (score 0):

After hours I found the answer : there should be id

```
editAuthor(name: $name, setBornTo: 1500)  {
      name
      born
      id

    }
```